# Jade - Declare array in extended file

Tags: pug

I want to do something like: I have a mixin which generate css links, and I want to declare it in a template file and I want to declare the parameters of the mixins in the main jade file.

#### mixins.jade

```
mixin includeCss(...cssFiles)
    each file in cssFiles
        link(rel="stylesheet", href=file)
```

#### layouts/template.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        +includeCss(cssIncludes)
```

#### index.jade

```
extends ./layouts/template
- var cssIncludes = ["style.css", "style2.css"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jade, [you need to use `block` for proper inheritance](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/). So you should use something like this instead. Otherwise, nothing you put in index.jade will be transferred back to what is extended.

#### layouts/template.jade

```
block vars
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    +includeCss(cssIncludes)
```

#### index.jade

```
extends ./layouts/template
block vars
  - var cssIncludes = ["style.css", "style2.css"]
```